# Новые и старые вопросы

Tags: обсуждение

***Коллеги,всех с Новых годом!***
Почему дизайн сайта так усложнился? Раньше показывались вопросы по мере их поступления. Т.е. сперва новые, а потом старые. Сейчас новые и старые вопросы перемешались. На верхних строках чаще видишь старые вопросы. Так возникает путаница: видишь вопрос, а не знаешь, новый это вопрос или старый. Надо открыть вопрос,чтобы понять, что это за вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И вас с праздником!

Кажется, вы можете сами выбирать, какие вопросы будут показываться первыми, воспользуйтесь сортировкой:
[image: сортировка]

Или по этой ссылке вы можете найти самые новые вопросы без ответа: https://rus.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest.

Comment: Большое, спасибо! Так легче работать.